# How can I get a text input to be positioned relative to an inset label using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I've built an input field that looks like what you see in the attached screenshot. The "Coin Name" text is a label and the "Gold Coin" text is a text input. Right now, the position of the input is just a flat padding-left value.

What I would like to do is have the input positioned relative to the label. Basically I want the text input to start just to the right of the label and if the label were to change size (due to localization, for instance) it adjusts automatically. You can see an example of this not working in the second image.

Is this possible? If so, how?

[image]
[image]

Edit: I've been asked to add my code, so here it is. Please don't feel the need to work within these bounds. If I can get the same visual effect using a different set of elements, that's fine by me.

Here is the handlebars code:

```
<div class="flexrow">
    <div class="coin">
        <div class="wrapper-rel">
            <label for="coin-name-{{key}}" class="inset-label">{{localize "SFC.CoinConfigItem.Name"}}</label>
            <input type="text" name="coin-name-{{key}}" title="Coin" value="{{coin.name}}" class="coin coin-text-input" placeholder='{{localize "SFC.CoinConfigItem.Name"}}' data-dtype="String">
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper-rel">
            <label for="coin-shortname-{{key}}" class="inset-label">{{localize "SFC.CoinConfigItem.ShortName"}}</label>
            <input type="text" name="coin-shortname-{{key}}" title="Coin" value="{{coin.shortName}}" class="coin coin-text-input" placeholder='{{localize "SFC.CoinConfigItem.ShortName"}}' data-dtype="String">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is my css:

```
#coin-config .inset-label {
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    height: 100%;
    padding: 4px 2px;
    font-size: small;
}

#coin-config .coin-text-input {
    padding-left: 85px;
}
```

Comment: Please post code. Anyone who wants to help you cannot reproduce what's in your screenshot without your code. Better yet, recreate the issue directly in a code snippet.

Comment: I intentionally didn't include any code because A) I'm sure my code sucks and B) I'm not looking for ways to change my code to make it work in case what I've done is way off base. Every other CSS question I found before posting this didn't include any code, so I didn't thing it would be an instant downvote if I didn't include any.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: grid;`, and a little more CSS:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.inputs {
  max-width: 666px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  row-gap: 12px;
  padding: 12px;
  margin: 40px auto;
  background-color: lightblue;
  border-radius: 12px;
}

label {
  padding: 6px 12px 6px 6px;
  border-radius: 12px 0 0 12px;
  border: solid 1px;
  border-right: 0;
  user-select: none;
}

span {
  border-radius: 0 12px 12px 0;
  border: solid 1px;
  border-left: 0;
}

input {
  border: 0;
  border-radius: inherit;
  padding: 0 12px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="inputs">
  <label for="coin-name">Coin Name</label>
  <span><input type="text" id="coin-name"></span>
  <label for="coin-shortname">Coin Shortname</label>
  <span><input type="text" id="coin-shortname"></span>
</div>
```